# Saving iptables on CentOS, and merging the previous rules with the newly saved ones?

Tags: centos, iptables

I added some new rules using `iptables` command, then saved them using `/sbin/service iptables save` as described here:

- http://www.centos.org/docs/4/html/rhel-rg-en-4/s1-iptables-saving.html

After that in the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file presents my new rules only. And all old rules are in the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables.save` file now.

As I understand, when the system restarts, the new rules will be applied but the old rules will not. How can I apply them both - new and old rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that when you've added the new rules, your old rule set was not loaded. So when you saved it only saved the newly added rules and overwrote all the old ones.

When you start adding or removing rules from your rule set, you have to first load the old one with `service iptables start`. Then you can do your edits, then do `service iptables save` to save the current rule set back into `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`. That way you don't have to do any merging.

If you want to merge these two files now, you will have to do some manual editing. Like for example load one of them, then manually copy paste the rules that you want to merge from the other one and insert them with the `iptables` command, then do the `service iptables save` again to save into the config file.

To make sure that next time when you reboot the rules from the file are loaded automatically, do `chkconfig iptables on`, this adds the iptables service to the default runlevel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're only option is going to be to manually merge the 2 files using a text editor. The entries in those 2 files are just plain text so you should be able to do this fairly easily.

#### Example

Here's my file, `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`:

```
$ sudo more /etc/sysconfig/iptables
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 5353 -d 224.0.0.251 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

When merging entries from the other file, `/etc/sysconfig/iptables.save` you just need to make sure that you keep the order somewhat intact. So if you have `-A INPUT ...` lines from that file, I'd put them towards the end of the ones that are already there.

Also I'd keep like rules next to each other. So keep entries for the `INPUT` table together, and rules for the `FORWARD` table together.

#### References

- [43.9.4. Saving IPTables Rules - RHEL 5 Deployment Guide](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-iptables-saving.html)